# Given a characteristic polynomial, and a constraint on $A+I,$ find Jordan form of $A.$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I thought this one was pretty neat, but I haven't been able to solve it, here it goes:

Let $A$ be a linear operator on a four dimensional complex vector space that satisfies $P(A) = A^4 + 2A^3 - 2A - I = 0.$ Given that $\dim(\text{Im}\,(A+I)) = 2,$ and $|\text{Tr}\,(A)| = 2,$ find the Jordan form of $A.$

---

Here's what I've been thinking.  First, $P(A)$ must be the characteristic polynomial of $A$ because it is a 4-th order monic polynomial with $A$ as a root.  If that's the case, we see that $Tr(A) = -2$ because of the $A^3$ coefficient in $P(A).$  Furthermore, we see that $\det(A) = 1,$ due to the coefficient of the $I$ term in $P(A).$  Thus, I conclude that $A$ is invertible.  Since $A$ is invertible, it may be diagonalized to the form
\begin{equation}
P^{-1}AP = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation} 
Given that $rk(A+I) = 2,$ I conclude that 2 eigenvalues (say $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$) are $-1.$  I check that $P(-1) = 0$ and it works out.

Then I have written that $Tr(A) = \sum \lambda_i = -2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 = -2,$ and $det(A) = \Pi \lambda_i = \lambda_3 \lambda_4 = 1,$ from the trace and determinant properties.  This leads to the conclusion that $\lambda_3 = i = -\lambda_4.$  However, $P(\pm i) \neq 0,$ so this must be wrong (I think).

If I were correct, and $A$ is diagonalizable, wouldn't the Jordan form just be a diagonal matrix?  Can anyone find where I made a mistake in my logic, or if someone sees a more direct way?

Comment: I see that not all invertible matrices are diagonalizable... now I guess I am looking for other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: I can conclude using decartes rule for sign changes in a polynomial that there is 1 positive real root to $P(A),$ and either $3$ or $1$ negative real root(s).  This makes me believe that since there are two eigenvalues with $-1$ value, the 3rd negative one must be the same, and the positive eigenvalue must be $+1$ to keep $|Tr(A)| = 2.$  However, this doesn't "feel" like how I should be solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p(t)=(t-1)(t+1)^3$, you know that the eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$. Since the algebraic multiplicity of $1$ is one, that would correspond to a $1\times1$ block in the Jordan form. The question is what happens with $-1$.

The fact that $\dim(\text{Im}\,(A+I))=2$ tells you that the geometric multiplicity of $-1$ is two, since $\dim\ker(A+I))=2$ (via the rank-nullity theorem). So $-1$ has two Jordan blocks. As these blocks correspond to three rows and columns in $A$ has has size one and the other size two. So the Jordan form of $A$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\ 0&0&-1&1\\ 0&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Great answer.  Is seeing that $p(t) = (t-1)(t+1)^3$ just a matter of expecting such a factorization, or is there some way you came to that?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E4%2B2t%5E3-2t-1%3D0) :)  But if I didn't have that option, I would have started looking for the simplest roots, and of course $1$ and $-1$ are the first you would try. After you divided by $t-1$ and $t+1$ you get a degree-two polynomial. In general, if the polynomial is bad enough, there is not a lot to do (still, for degree four there is a formula for all 4 roots, although it can get nasty).

Comment: In fact, since you are given that $\operatorname{rank}(A + I) = 2$, you know that $-1$ must be an eigenvalue of $A$ and so $(t + 1)$ must divide $p(t) = t^4 + 2t^3 - 2t - 1$ (as $(t+1)$ must divide the minimal polynomial which divides $p(t)$) so you can check which power of $t + 1$ divides $p(t)$ by performing long division and then you will be left with a linear factor.